# Как добавить объекты другого класса в ArrayList?

Tags: java, коллекции

Привет. Есть класс, который имеет два значения int и string. Мне нужно добавить обьекты этого класса в коллекцию ArrayList, потом нужно работать с этими обьектами и с их значениями (int, string).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Colourize {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] Matrix;
    Matrix = new int [][]  {                
            {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
            {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
            {1, 1, 0, 1, 0},  
    };

    List<Vertex> Graph = new ArrayList<Vertex>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.length; i++) {
        Vertex a = new Vertex();
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < Matrix.length; j++) {
            if (Matrix[i][j] == 1) count++;
        }
        a.links = count;
        a.colour = "white";
        Graph.add(a);
    }
    Iterator<Vertex> iterator = Graph.iterator();        
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(obj.toString());
    }

    }
}
```

Вывод такой: 
Vertex@6fe99db4
Vertex@5270cdd2
Vertex@6bd8c046
Vertex@63376afa
Vertex@4b5075f9

Помогите сделать вывод адекватным. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переопределите метод toString() в классе Vertex, и будет вам счастье!

Comment: Спасибо, дружище!)

Comment: @thejadefalcon, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).